# How to sort array of CoreData objects by integer attributes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an array of CoreData objects, each object is `Person` and each `Person` has an `age` attribute which is of type Integer32.

My array is filled with `Person` objects. I want to sort my array by their `age` attribute.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES]
];

NSArray *sortedPeople = [people sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"%@", sortedPeople);
```

This will work regardless of whether you do or do not choose to "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when creating your `NSManagedObject` subclass (if you decide to even create them)

Answer (score 0):

Say "people" is your array of Person objects you want sorted...

```
NSArray *sortedPeople = [people sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *p1, Person *p2) {
    if (p1.age > p2.age) return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (p1.age < p2.age) return NSOrderedAscending;
    else return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Comment: 'else' is redundant here since you're returning in each positive case.